# Django using select options in registration forms.py

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Django using select options in registration forms.py

I put some teams in my `models.py` in this way:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    TEAM = (('python', 'python'), ('php', 'php'))
    ...
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    member_of = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TEAM, default=TEAM[0][0])
   
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

and my `forms.py` is like:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        #fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'member_of']
```

So when I want to use it in my `registration.html` I am not able to create account:

```
<div class="group text-left">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">team</label>
    <select name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
        {% for team in registration_form.member_of %}
            {{team}}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

and also it is not important to use `registration_form.member_of`. If I only put `member_of` in my `forms.py` I can't register new users.

#Update:

My registration page is:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
    <!-- Begin HEAD -->
    {% include 'account/user/snippets/head.html' %}
    <!-- End HEAD -->
    <body class="bg-white">
        <!-- Begin Preloader -->
        {% include 'account/user/snippets/page-preloader.html' %}
        <!-- End Preloader -->
        <!-- Begin Container -->
        <div class="container-fluid no-padding h-100">
            <div class="row flex-row h-100 bg-white">
                <!-- Begin Left Content -->
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-5 no-padding">
                    <div class="theme-bg background-05">
                        <div class="theme-overlay overlay-04"></div>
                        <div class="authentication-col-content mx-auto">
                            <h1 class="gradient-text-01">
test
                            </h1>
                            <span class="description">
test
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Left Content -->
                <!-- Begin Right Content -->
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-7 my-auto no-padding">
                    <!-- Begin Form -->
                    <div class="authentication-form mx-auto">
                        <div class="logo-centered">
                            <a href="{% url 'panel' %}">
                                <img src="{% static '/img/logo.png' %}" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3>create account</h3>
                        <form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% if 'password2' in registration_form.errors %}
                                <h3><span style="width:400px;"><span style="width:400px;" class="badge badge-text-small text-white badge-danger">error</span></span></h3>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.username}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>username</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.first_name}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>anme</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.last_name}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>family</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group text-left">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">status</label>
                                <select name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                                    {% for team in registration_form.member_of %}
                                        {{team}}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.password1}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.password2}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>confirm</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sign-btn text-center">
                                <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-lg btn-gradient-01" value="create account">
                            </div>
                            <div class="register">
test
                                <br>
                                <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
                            </div> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Form -->                      
                </div>
                <!-- End Right Content -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Row -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Container -->     
        <!-- Begin Vendor Js -->
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/base/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/base/core.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- End Vendor Js -->
        <!-- Begin Page Vendor Js -->
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/app/app.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- End Page Vendor Js -->
    </body>
</html>                 </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.password1}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group material-input">
                                {{registration_form.password2}}
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label>confirm</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sign-btn text-center">
                                <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-lg btn-gradient-01" value="create account">
                            </div>
                            <div class="register">
test
                                <br>
                                <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
                            </div> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Form -->                      
                </div>
                <!-- End Right Content -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Row -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Container -->     
        <!-- Begin Vendor Js -->
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/base/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/base/core.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- End Vendor Js -->
        <!-- Begin Page Vendor Js -->
        <script src="{% static '/vendors/js/app/app.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- End Page Vendor Js -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you remove member part, does your user register? I am trying to see if you have other problems besides your member_of field rendering and validation.

Comment: Yes users can register without `member_of`

Comment: please shwo your full html template

Comment: also, why are you manually rendering your form?

Comment: I updated the question. What do you mean by rendering manually? sorry I am new with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are manually rendering your form. In this case, if without `member_of` field, registration is working, you want to change your template.

```
# I assume you have other fields you are rending manually
# such as
# {{registration_form.username}}
# {{registration_form.first_name}}

# for team, just use:
  
  {{registration_form.member_of}}
```

Basically replace this part

```
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">وضعیت</label>
                                <select name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                                    {% for team in registration_form.member_of %}
                                        {{team}}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
```

with

```
{{registration_form.member_of}}
```

**If you want to add some style**

There are two ways to do this.

1. one option is to use `widget`. I think even without this need, you should utilize form widget as much as possible. For example, if you do not like the dropdown which is the default by django, and want to change to Radio button, you can use `widget`. Besides that, widget can also allow you to add `css attributes`. Here is the example of how to use it:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'member_of']
        widgets = {
            'member_of': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs= {
                 'class': 'choice_class'})
        }
```

if CheckboxInput is not what you want, check out other widget
doc is here [about selector and checkbox widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selector-and-checkbox-widgets)

2. I like to use `widget` for when I want to change the default widget of the field. But I do not like to use it to set css attributes. I think for just setting css attributes, `widget-tweaks` is a better option. Because `widget-tweaks` add css attributes in the html template.

To use `widget-tweaks`,

a. install

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

b. add to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'widget_tweaks',
    ...
]
```

c. in template,

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{registration_form.member_of |add_class: "member_of_class"}}
```

Comment: Yes That's perfect, I did that manually because I need to make a better style to my select option form. Now it works but the style is nasty :). I know this is not by django. but could you please help me?

Comment: what kind of style you are looking for. do you want to add a css class to the field?

Comment: do you want to make it like radiobutton? or you are happy with checkbox, but want to be able tohave more control?

Comment: No, It's ok in dropdown but I like to have a dropdown in whole row or something

Comment: updated. please check all the answer, before decide which way to go.